# as I install pymodis?

Tags: python, r, modis, pymodis

unfortunately I have tried to download images bulk MODIS (NDIV and LST), but since the USGS server ((http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/) exchange ftp http, based codes R and python obsolete because I know are based on fTP, I tried using pymodis but I could not install I followed all the steps of the page pymodis (http://www.pymodis.org/) but still I could not can someone help me install it or a way to download bulk data ??

Comment: Is this a GIS question? seems to be an access issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just used pyModis the other day, it downloaded fine.

Two things to check:

1) Do you use the current version? The installation works like this:

```
# http://www.pymodis.org/info.html#how-to-install-pymodis
pip install pyModis
```

If that does not work, then try to upgrade:

```
pip install pyModis --upgrade
```

2) Register at NASA:

Importantly, to be able to download data you need user and password provided by NASA. Hence you need to be **registered at NASA** first!

New user registration at https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/users/new .
Now login and move to your profile page (if you are already a registered user, just login).

Next enable the "applications" at: https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/home
Now go to the "My application" tab and approve the following applications "LP DAAC Data Pool" and "Earthdata Search".

At this point you are able to bulk download data using pyModis (http://www.pymodis.org).